# How can I go about adding a premium membership model to an existing website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am not necessarily looking for a definitive answer (although those are welcome!) but perhaps be pointed in the right direction.

To provide some background: I've just been brought onto a web development project by a pretty well known website - If you haven't used it, I am sure you have at least heard of it. Anyway, my task is to single handedly create a premium membership model for a specific area of the website that already exists. The area is currently available to all, however they are planning on giving access to premium members only going forward - that's where I come in. The only problem is, I have no clue where to begin as I have never created a premium/freemium membership model before.

My current skills: proficient in Ruby, and Rails.

Any input or direction would be great!

Thanks.

Edit: Thanks for the suggestions! I didn't anticipate this many angles. All suggestions seem like great solutions and I am going to look into them further to see which fits best with the project!

*Disclaimer: if this post doesn't meet S.O.F policy then please feel free to remove it. Albeit, I am not sure where else to ask as this has been my go to place for Rails web dev queries/problems up to this point.*

Comment: https://tutorials.railsapps.org/rails-stripe-membership-saas

Comment: simple /naive answer add an attribute to the user to indicate premium, put all parts that are to be premium behind a before filter that requires user to have premium flag? Or does it need to be more than that?

Comment: I would check out this railscast where Ryan Bates covers "Adding Stripe to a Rails Application" http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe?view=asciicast

Comment: Agree with @Doon. Just add a premium field to the user, and check it on restricted pages.

Answer (score 2):

Use [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for authorisation, requiring only a current_user method in your controller. The following is copied from the README:

Your permissions are defined in an Ability class. CanCan includes a Rails 3 generator for creating this class.

```
rails g cancan:ability
```

Define which user is authorised to what using the can method:

```
can [:update, :destroy], [Article, Comment]
```

Check whether user is authorised to :destroy a comment:

```
if can?(:destroy, @comment) then
   # user can destroy comment
```

There is more available on the website, but this should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish between free and premium users. The easy way is to add some sort of 'premium' boolean column/flag into the User model.

The actual payment processing and handling of recurring transactions is much more complex issue. You should take a look at Recurly as they make it very easy. And if you're in US you can even use their payment gateway. I had to use Braintree instead and can recommend them as well.